# Can you use CSS to select and style a string inside a paragraph(s)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

is it possible to pick out and style a particular word in a paragraph using just css? So for example in the sentence "hello my name is nick, hello to you all", would it be possible to target the word "hello" wherever it appears and to add a rule, such as changing the color of hello anytime it appears? I don't want to have to add a span tag around every hello that appears.

I would like to do this in only css if possible. css3 is fine to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275776/is-there-a-css-selector-to-select-text-inline-blocks-within-a-rectangular-box

Comment: I doubt this is possible, but I look forward to the creative answers that you might get.

Comment: You don't want to use `<span>`? Well, you're in luck, you can use `<mark>`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'd need to use javascript for that.  Or, if you're using PHP/ASP...etc, you could add spans around any designated word(s) automatically before the page renders.

Comment: Thanks - ended up using PHP and doing a find/replace, replacing the word with the word plus span tags just like you suggested :)

Comment: Glad to help!  If this answer answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the answer to help future users who find your question.

Answer (score 2):

CSS has 2* Pseudo-Elements:

`::first-line` and `::first-letter`. These are the only possibilities to target only a part of  the innerhtml of a Tag.

(*ofc it has more, i mean for the purpose of selecting only a part of the innerhtml.)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the contents of the para and have patience you can wrap each of those words that you need to highlight in a span tag. Assign them the same class and then style it.

Answer (score 1):

For fine control over any particular word, or fragment, you'd have to wrap it into a span and style the span, as others said.

However, there are also the `:first-line` and `:first-letter` pseudo-elements, available since CSS2. So, for example, you can have the first letter have a different font-size, and the whole first line have a different color, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5ccuX/):

```
p:first-letter {font-size: 30px;}
p:first-line {color: #FF0000;}
```

Comment: These are not pseudo-classes, these are pseudo-elements. These have also been available since the halcyon days of CSS1 (albeit not supported until IE5.5), and are therefore the first two ever of their kind. The pseudo-elements that were introduced in CSS2 are `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: Thanks for the information!I have always been confused about the pseudo-class vs -element naming.  Now I read the specs. The [CSS1 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#pseudo-classes-and-pseudo-elements) are not very informative about it, but  the [CSS2 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements) are very clear.

Answer (score 0):

What I know its not possible to target textnode, you can do it by using Javascript. Wrap the Hello word with a span tag and set the properties to the SPAN tag

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors work on tags or pseudo clases, not querying your text. Check the reference http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/, maybe you can find something useful here.